# How can I tell if my Samsung S7 supports connecting to a wired ethernet via a usb OTG cable?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I want to connect my Samsung S7 to a wired ethernet connection using something like [this usb micro > Ethernet hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00L32UUJK)

Their instructions say to look for Ethernet option under Settings> Networking 
But I see not such option.

Folks are reporting that [the Samsung does not support wired connections](https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7/661581-how-can-i-connect-my-galaxy-s7-ethernet-adapter.html)

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Like any other computer system Android also requires a driver for talking to a device.

However unlike regular PCs you can't just install a driver, instead you only have the drivers the manufacturer included when building the Android system.

In a terminal or on an `adb shell` you can list all the drivers that were included in your kernel:

```
ls /system/lib/modules
```

If the list contains for example the driver `usbnet` there is a chance that an USB Ethernet adapter may work.